# Frequency of gaps between consecutive prime numbers

Tags: calculus, integration, prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics, prime-gaps

This plot, from  [Odlyzko, Rubinstein & Wolf, 1999](http://www.dtc.umn.edu/%7Eodlyzko/doc/jumping.champions.pdf), shows the frequency of the gaps between consecutive primes of a given size.

[image]

Where $N(x,d)$ is the number of primes $p \leq x$ such that $p+2d$ is the smallest prime $> p$.

My question is what happens to the plot as $x \to \infty$? In particular, does the gradient of the plot approach a specific value? What about $\frac{N(x,d)}{\pi(x)}$ ?

This explanation is provided in the paper:

> **Figure 1** Log plot of $\log {N(x,d)}$, the number of jumps of length $2d$ between primes up to $x$, for $x = 2^{20}, 2^{22}, \ldots, 2^{44}$. Integrating (2-8) by parts and taking logarithms we see that, for fixed $x$, the graph should follow a straight line with small perturbations  of size $\log{A_{d,1}}$ (see text); this can be seen in the figure.

> Where (2-8) is the approximation:
> $$N(d,x) \sim A_{d,1} \int_2^x \frac{\exp{(-2d / \log t )}}{\log^2{t}} dt   .$$

I am having difficulty performing the integration

\begin{align}
\int \frac{\exp{(-2d / \log t )}}{\log^2{t}} dt &=  \int \frac{t}{2d} \frac{2d\exp{(-2d / \log t )}}{t\log^2{t}} dt \\
&= \int \frac{t}{2d} \frac{d}{dt} \left[ \exp{(-2d / \log t )} \right] dt \\
&= \frac{t}{2d}  \exp{(-2d / \log t )} - \int \frac{1}{2d} \left[ \exp{(-2d / \log t )} \right] dt
\end{align}

and I don't see how to make progress.

Answer (score 1):

Using the relationship $e^x=\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^K\frac{x^k}{k!}\right)$ leads to formula (1) below for $f_d(x)=\int\limits_2^x\frac{e^{-\frac{2 d}{\log (t)}}}{\log ^2(t)}\,dt$ which seems to converge fairly rapidly. The function $f_d(x)$ can also be approximated using the Mathematica $\text{NIntegrate}$ function as illustrated in formula (2) below.

---

$$f_d(x)=\underset{K\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\left(\sum _{k=0}^K \frac{(2 d)^k (\Gamma (-k-1,-\log (x))-\Gamma (-k-1,-\log (2)))}{k!}\right)\tag{1}$$

$$f_d(x)\approx\text{NIntegrate}\left[\frac{e^{-\frac{2 d}{\log (t)}}}{\log ^2(t)},\{t,2,x\}\right]\tag{2}$$

---

The following figure illustrates formula (1) for $f_1(x)$ above in orange overlaid on the blue reference function defined in formula (2) above where formula (1) is evaluated with the upper limit $K=100$.

---

[image: Illustration of formulas (1) and (2)]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of formulas (1) and (2) for $f_1(x)$ in orange and blue respectively.

---

The following figure illustrates formula (2) for $f_d(x)$ for $d\in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ where the blue top curve corresponds to $f_1(x)$ and the purple bottom curve corresponds to $f_5(x)$.

---

[image: Illustration of formula (2)]

**Figure (2)**: Illustration of formula (2) for $f_d(x)$ for $d\in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$

---

Note $N(x,1)=\pi_2(x)$ where $\pi_2(x)$ counts the number of twin-prime pairs $(p, p+2)$ with $p\le x$ (see [OEIS A071538](https://oeis.org/A071538)). Also see [Wikipedia: Twin prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime) and [Weisstein, Eric W. "Twin Primes." From MathWorld--A Wolfram Web Resource](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TwinPrimes.html).